How do I locate the SQLIte database on Android
I tried the following code but it does not appear to work.
    public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, getDatabasePath(context), null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private static String getDatabasePath(Context context) {
        // Obtenir le chemin du dossier "Documents"
        File documentsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        // Créer le dossier "Documents" s'il n'existe pas
        if (!documentsDir.exists()) {
            documentsDir.mkdirs();
        }
        // Retourner le chemin complet de la base de données
        return new File(documentsDir, DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
    }
`
```


You're trying to store the SQLite database in the public Documents directory, which isn't the recommended approach for Android apps.
Here’s a proper way to do it:
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "your_database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        // Use the app's private database directory
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Get the database file path (for debugging purposes)
    public String getDatabasePath() {
        return context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Create your tables here
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Handle database upgrades here
    }

    // Optional: Method to check if database exists
    public boolean databaseExists() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    // Optional: Method to get database size
    public long getDatabaseSize() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        return dbFile.length();
    }
}

What you need to know about SQLite database location in Android:
Default Location:

Android stores app databases in the private app directory: /data/data/your.package.name/databases/
You don't need to specify this path manually; Android handles it

To use the database:
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

To find the actual path (for debugging):
String path = dbHelper.getDatabasePath();
Log.d("Database Path", path);

Note the following:

Don't store databases in public directories like Documents
Use the app's private storage for security
Let Android manage the database location through Context.getDatabasePath()
The database is automatically created in the correct location when you first call getWritableDatabase()

EDIT:
I created a database directory to ensure compatibility across all Android versions. Here’s the updated code:
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "your_database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        // Use the app's private database directory
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        
        // Create database directory if it doesn't exist
        File dbDirectory = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases");
        if (!dbDirectory.exists()) {
            dbDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    // Get the database file path (for debugging purposes)
    public String getDatabasePath() {
        return context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Create your tables here
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Handle database upgrades here
    }

    // Optional: Method to check if database exists
    public boolean databaseExists() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    // Optional: Method to get database size
    public long getDatabaseSize() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        return dbFile.length();
    }
}

The directory creation is important because:

On some Android versions (particularly older ones), the databases directory isn't automatically created
If the directory doesn't exist when trying to create the database, it can cause a SQLiteException
This is especially important when the app is first installed or if the user clears app data

The added code:
File dbDirectory = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases");
if (!dbDirectory.exists()) {
    dbDirectory.mkdirs();
}

ensures that the databases directory exists before SQLite tries to create the database file.

You have omitted the creation of the database directory, if it doesn't exist when calling the getDatabasePath method, which for some early versions of Android, can cause issues.

That's a good point. I will go through my answer again and edit accordingly, shortly. Thanks

Fix: I updated the code to ensure compatibility across all Android versions

You should a) ensure that a valid Context is passed when calling the getDatabasePath method and importantly, if using the default Android SQLite database location, b) use the Context's getDatabasePath method.
e.g.
File documentsDir = context.getDatabasePath("whatever_as_it_does_not_matter_as_dir_will_be_the_same").parentFile


Note the file name as it is descriptive (i.e. the name, if wanting JUST the directory (the parent), is irrelevant (as long as it is valid)).

note that you would very likely use DATABASE_NAME, as in  context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).parentFile


Although the link to getDatabasePath mentions openOrCreateDatabase.... this method will be invoked by other convenience API class/methods such as the SQLiteOpenHelper class.

It very much appears that your Database class extends the SQliteOpenHelper class.


You may wish to refer to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage. However, note that this tries to push one towards utilising Android Room and thus hides the fact that Room utilises the underlying SQLite API, which is obviously perfectly valid to utilise without resorting to utilising Room.


